# I can’t understand how can i load fastcgi module to apache and run php :S …?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

Is there anyone may explain how to run fastcgi as a module in Apache server ( 2.x ) on windows platform, step by step.

I ve googled many sites and tested many things but i couldnt make it.

I want to run php with fastcgi using Apache server.

Please help. Thank you.

I ve already have latest fastcgi.dll and added http.conf file LoadModule fastcgi_module "/xampp/apache/modules/mod_fastcgi-2.4.6-AP22.dll"
and its loaded because apache can restart.

What should i do next steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Http.conf file;

1 - You need to load fast_cgi module
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.dll

2 - add this :

```
     <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>  
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi .php  
# Where to look for the php.ini file?  
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC        "c:/xampp/php"  
# Set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS to greater than or equal to FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess  
# to prevent php-cgi process from exiting before all requests completed  
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS      1000  
# Maximum requests a process should handle before it is terminated  
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess       1000  
# Maximum number of PHP processes  
FcgidMaxProcesses             15  
# Number of seconds of idle time before a php-cgi process is terminated  
FcgidIOTimeout             120  
FcgidIdleTimeout                120  
#Path to php-cgi  
FcgidWrapper "c:/xampp/php/php-cgi.exe" .php  
# Define the MIME-Type for ".php" files  
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php  
</IfModule>
```

3 - make sure you give permission to your root directory to run CGI
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

For a good information you may visit [here.](http://fuzzytolerance.info/code/apache-mod_fcgid-and-php-on-windows/)